# ¿Cómo obtener dirección IP tipo ipV6 C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Desarrollo una aplicación Asp.Net WebForms y necesito obtener la dirección IP desde donde se conecta un cliente a el servidor…pude hacerlo para IpV4, pero también me gustaría poder hacerlo para IpV6

Hize esto para obtener dirección IpV4…Como puedo hacerlo para IpV6?

```
   public string GetIpAddress(System.Web.HttpRequest request)
        {
            // Recuperamos la IP de la máquina del cliente
            // Primero comprobamos si se accede desde un proxy
            string ipAddress1 = request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            // Acceso desde una máquina particular
            string ipAddress2 = request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            string ipAddress = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress1) ? ipAddress2 : ipAddress1;
            // Devolvemos la ip
            return ipAddress;
        }
```

Comment: No entiendo tu necesidad de hacerlo, lo que buscas es obtener la cadena de ip con formato ipv6?

Comment: Deberias tenerlo en cuenta para el futuro porque antes o despues IPv6 acabara imponiendose, asi que conviene dejarlo previsto en laaplicacion y aceptar las direcciones IPv6 ...Esto lo obtuve del siguiente link ..   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/b1618e6d-a4b9-4da2-a2b6-52a52c942a87/como-obtener-la-ip-del-cliente-que-se-conecta-a-mi-servidor-?forum=netfxwebes

Comment: Si no me equivoco, con la implementación que vos tenes ya estas obteniendo las ip ipv6, sólo que deberías usar el método `public IPAddress MapToIPv6()`

Comment: Ok Juan Salvador Portugal ...si tienes un ejemplo seria genial ..esa es mi pregunta ¿como lo implemento?

Comment: Aquí tienes la misma pregunta y su solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795398/ipv4-mapped-ipv6-addresses

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado un stack donde te recogen todas las ips locales del equipo y luego realizan un filtro para sacar las que necesites.

[How to get IPv4 and IPv6 address of local machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411486/how-to-get-ipv4-and-ipv6-address-of-local-machine)

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [answer] para aprender a realizar una buena respuesta. Las preguntas que solo contienen un enlace son consideradas como de baja calidad, ya que si la página enlazada desaparece, la respuesta queda sin sentido.